Why do I get a 401 calling a logic app from APIM
I have a requirement to have a Logic App the reads a file out of blob storage and return it. The goal will be to put this behind APIM. I created 2 stateless Logic Apps (standard and consumption models). They both read the json file and return it with no authentication. I can call them from any browser/workstation and they return the file with no credentials required.
I created an APIM and tried using the Logic App I can see (the consumption model) and also created one manually for the other logic app. When I test the APIM call I get a 401 error.
I have the API calls set to not require a subscription but that didn't do anything. I can call the get method no problem on the ECHO api call so I copied it and just swapped its endpoint with my Logic Apps and get a 401 again.
Any ideas as to why I can call the logic app directly unauthenticated and its fine, but the APIM gets a 401?
I've tried to dummy this down as much as possible. I created a Standard model Logic App with a samp workflow that returns success in the body. I can call it from any browser:
Simply returns the word Success
In my APIM I created a new API of type HTTP (manual) and just added the endpoint. I try and test it and get a 401. I can assign it a product and uncheck require subscription and it still gives 401
Adding the endpoint to HTTP

Can you share a screen shot of the APIM and Logic app

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@RithwikBojja created a simpler example and added a couple screenshots

Firstly, I have created api calling as below:
Add API:

Created :

I just added Logic App, names , not added any API URL suffix and created.
Then when subscription is enabled :

when called:

When subscription is not enabled :

when called:

In APIM Instance:

If you still get 401, I would suggest you to raise a support request as this is abnormal behavior.

Thanks very much for your detailed answer!! Using this method I was able to replicate it. However, my logic apps weren't showing so I had to create a new one as a consumption model and then your tutorial worked. Ours currently are standard (not multi tenant) so they need to be setup and configured manually but maybe I can still leverage this information.
